# Can the production org id corresponding to a sandbox org id be found via Apex?

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, lma

The use case is that we have added additional licensing parameters to the LMA License object that our managed package reads from the LMA via a @RestResource site added to the LMA org.

This works fine for production orgs that have an LMA License object but not for sandboxes that do not have a corresponding LMA License object. Hence the quick fix would be to identify the production org id (when in the sandbox org) and always pass that in the read request...

**PS** The lack of a license for sandboxes is awkward in other situations too - see [LMA should create licenses for sandbox installs](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrmIAAS).

Comment: I don't know of any way of doing this, but maybe you could somehow capture the production org Id (post install script or at some point when they run your app in product) in a private custom setting, then read it once your in the sandbox?

Comment: I just posted an idea for Salesforce to add a Lookup to the corresponding Production Org's license record: [LMA Licenses for Sandboxes need Lookup field to the Production Org License](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfZRAA0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any way of doing this, but maybe you could somehow capture the production org Id (post install script or at some point when they run your app in product) in a private custom setting, then read it once your in the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks. This license logic is already in the post install script and has a private custom setting so I'll go with that unless something simpler gets posted here. I'll mark your answer as accepted once its all working.

Comment: Welcome, neat LMA integration btw! ;-)