# Querying all the SandboxInfo via REST API

Tags: rest, tooling-api, tooling

Our architecture uses Salesforce to send some emails to clients automatically, so to reproduce the full architecture in a demo environment we need to have an identical instance of Salesforce.

We can use a Sandbox, we have found the SandboxProcess and Sandbox. How do we query all the instances via rest api?

Comment: Why do you need to query all sandbox instance? I belive its not exactly possible, you can refer this 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/can-the-production-org-id-corresponding-to-a-sandbox-org-id-be-found-via-apex

Comment: We need to issue a refresh to the sandbox via API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick we had to understand is that sObjects are not implementing REST resource "collection" default behaviour, i.e.

```
GET /services/data/v40.0/tooling/sobjects/SandboxInfo/
```

will non return all the Sandbox Info. Therefore one has to use the QUERY endpoint:

```
GET /services/data/v40.0/tooling/query/?q=
Select+id,SandboxName+from+SandboxInfo
```

We now have the Name and Id (they are stable, so one could check them the UI) and we can issue a

```
PATCH /services/data/v40.0/tooling/sobjects/SandboxInfo/ID
```

with body

```
{ “licenseType”: “DEVELOPER” }
```

Comment: Small bug in the above query @Emondo1984  name isn't a valid field, its "SandboxName" instead -- but this was a big help!

Comment: @Edmondo1984 do you want to mark your answer as accepted to get this out of the unanswered questions queue.

Answer (score 0):

With an accesstoken/session id to the corresponding production org you can use the tooling api via REST to query the [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm).

Comment: I tried to query from the workbench but was unable to query the records ( I was only able to query the sObject definition of SandboxInfo)