# Salesforce available sandbox license for organization

Tags: soql, rest-api

I want to get the Available Sandbox license count for the different types of Sandboxes available to my org through SOQL or REST endpoint. Is there any way to achieve this?
I know we have the sanboxinfo api but that provides the info about Sandboxes that we are using and not the available count of different Sandbox type available to my org.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a straightforward way to obtain it with SOQL, in the sandbox itself. You could do a Tooling API callout to the production org and query the [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) table.

Refer the [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193718/how-to-find-the-environment-type-of-salesforce-sandbox)

Refer the [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193280/querying-all-the-sandboxinfo-via-rest-api)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: SandboxInfo API looks to provide the information about the Sandboxes which are being used and not the available Sandboxes and their types. Please correct if my understanding is wrong? I want to fetch the information about the number of different available Sandboxes which i can use and not the information about the sandboxes that are currently in use, thanks.